# Close uzbl-browser on certain url

Tags: browser, user-input

I'm using uzbl-browser for a kiosk computer. I'd like to send "close" (or kill) to my uzbl-browser's instance when a user opens a certain URL. What is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

My aim is not that.
I have a survey and i would show it before logout. If user close it then logout. Otherwise wait until last page of survey (identify by a "certain url") and the close uzbl and logout
My solution is that.

Add this to config file

```
@on_event   LOAD_FINISH    spawn @scripts_dir/survey_end_check.sh
```

and in my survey_end_check.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $UZBL_URI = "http://yoururl" ];
then
  sleep 5
  echo "exit" | socat - unix-connect:$UZBL_SOCKET
fi
```

variant in order to find ad certain string in final page.
After grep, $? is 0 if grep succeeded

```
#!/bin/sh

end=`echo "@<document.getElementsByClassName('success')[0].innerText>@" | socat - unix-connect:$UZBL_SOCKET | grep -q 'Success!'; echo $?`

if [ $end -eq 0 ];
then
  sleep 5
  echo "exit" | socat - unix-connect:$UZBL_SOCKET
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were a user on that computer and had any window, browser or not, closing itself without warning I'd consider this an application crash and try again.

Forcing that behavior on your users may not be the most informative choice.

What you want to look into is a transparent proxy that can filter content. This is how most companies restrict their employees from visiting certain pages.

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is one example of a proxy solution commonly used for this, usually setup together with [SquidGuard](http://www.squidguard.org/). [This guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/web-filtering-on-squid-proxy) will get you started.

Alternatively you could also use a DNS solution that redirects all filtered hostnames to a given page. [DansGuardian](http://dansguardian.org/?page=whatisdg) is a possibility here.

A search on stackoverflow will also give you answers as several users already asked similar questions.